# Añadir etiqueta XDebug

Tags: soporte, etiquetas

He intentado añadir la etiqueta XDebug en una pregunta pero no existe, ¿se podría crear?

Tiene su homóloga en StackOverflow (inglés) pero en la versión en español no está disponible.

XDebug es una extensión de PHP que permite la depuración con NetBeans, PHPStorm...

https://xdebug.org/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

He visto la pregunta donde la necesitabas y le he añadido la etiqueta [xdebug](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/xdebug).

Cuando tengas 300 de reputación, ganarás el privilegio de crear etiquetas tal y cómo se explica en [Privilegios](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/privileges)